# Is it possible to block the transition to edit mode for a linked object?

Tags: edit-mode

I have a main object from which the linked objects are multiplied. I want to make it so that I cannot switch to edit mode on all linked objects.
Now there is such a function as disable selection. It prohibits interacting with an object in object mode. I need its counterpart for edit mode.
I have re-read a lot of topics, but some of them are dated 9 years ago, so I decided to create this topic. Perhaps this is already in a fundamentally new blender.

ChatGPT suggested enabling "Object Lock Modes" in "Custom Properties". Enabling or disabling the "Object Lock Modes" checkbox in the "edit menu" does not help in any way. I can still press TAB and change the model grid.

Version Blender 3.4.1

up::

Assets in project - these are the created props for the project that have a collision. You can change them.

PROPS --> Room_1 object is a duplicate linked. They only need to be moved. It is necessary to prohibit entry into edit mode. They serve for a meta file with the coordinates of objects in the room.
[image]

Comment: This makes no sense, linked objects can't be edited by definition, and ChatGPT's suggestions are once again absurd

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos If they can't be edited, why then when I select any object by pressing TAB, I can switch to Edit Mode and by moving the vertices, all changes are applied to the linked objects?

Comment: @Maxim_R: i think you confused linked copy and linked object. Link object is what you do via file -> link and linked copy is object -> duplicate linked (what you meant i think, but you wrote "linked object" which Duarte wrote - cannot be edited.

Comment: Although I understand that you mean linked duplicate/copy, I do not know why you want to stop the linked copies from going into _Edit Mode_? Because you do not like how it looks? Cannot think of another reason... Or to stop them from being edited as well? But that's what a linked copy is for, if you do not want them to inherit the changes, why make a linked duplicate in the first place? Or are you just making linked duplicates because you do not know how to create simple unlinked duplicates? Alt+D makes linked duplicates, Ctrl+D duplicates without linking.

Comment: Apart from that, in my Blender versions 3.6.1, 3.5, 3.4, 3.3 unselected linked objects do not switch into _Edit Mode_ when I press `Tab` on one of them. This is in older versions. Are you talking about linked duplicates or something like instances?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann You have exactly understood my point. I apologize if I asked the wrong question. I'm talking about objects created via `alt+D`. The fact is that I store models in a separate zone, where they also have parents and collisions. For the task, I create linked duplicates of a drawble object, without collision and parents. After the linked duplicates check, I arrange them by location. And in order to avoid accidental misklik, I wanted to disable the ability to edit objects on linked duplicates. By allowing changes to be applied to them only from the main object from a separate zone.

Comment: If they are linked duplicates, they will only take changes from linked objects. I'm sorry, I cannot recreate in my head what you are exactly doing there, what "separate zone" you have there, how the objects are parented, what allowing changes only from a separate zone means etc. and I still do not understand why the linked duplicates all go into _Edit Mode_ if you are using 3.4.1, because on my PC they only do it in older versions or on instances. Maybe you should upload an example file to https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit it into your question.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann If you can, take a look. I updated the theme and added a blender file.